# j2ME Polish Getting to know if the Device is touch-enabled

Tags: mobile, java-me, touch, j2mepolish

my question for today is:

Is there a way for me to detect if a cellphone is touch capable by code on J2ME? Or even J2ME Polish?

Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In J2ME MIDP 2 - [Canvas.hasPointerEvents()](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Canvas.html#hasPointerEvents%28%29) *Checks if the platform supports pointer press and release events*